authentication powershell from Linux Centos 7 to RHEL9 problem
This script powershell work well until Centos 7
  $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $credential -Authentication Negotiate

where gssntlmssp was installed...
Now I need to move this machine to RHEL9 and the same powershell script give me this error
New-PSSession: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] Connecting to remote server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX failed with the following error message : acquiring creds with username only failed No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic

How can I solve? the package gssntlmssp is removed from RHEL9.
Thank a lot!

Looks like you might have to build gss-ntlmssp from source

unable to build; many errors
